# Common features of a robust CMS

Tags: content-management-system

This is not a direct code question, however, I think it may be useful. After google-ing for a while, I can't find a definitive answer....

A while back, I built a rudimentary CMS for shcool. Image upload, gallery, text, a basic captcha, etc. Basically a blog that you could upload images to. My quesiton is this:

Could any of you clever ducks tell me what features a robust, solid, home-made CMS should contain? I don't want to make a super fancy pants sort of site, but I do want to flesh it out a little. My current job is in Sharepoint design, and I don't want to lose any of the PHP skills that course taught me.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. The best product is a product that reaches the requirements of the customer.

But I would say:

1. Dynamic menu
2. Dynamic pages
3. Different type of pages - front page, posts, lists, media, gallery
4. Secure back end
5. Dynamic user configuration
6. A install script
7. Template editor, where you can define modules
8. Maybe a offline post editor, with a up-loader (Drag a .doc file in a folder, and the file is automatically added as a post on the page)

Comment: Oh this is sweet, thanks for replying. Pardon my stupidity, but I have a couple of follow ups.  I have a few of these covered, noteably 1,2,3 (mostly). But what do you mean by 'dynamic user config.'? That they can choose what elements they wish to implement (as in image gallery, media gallery - no posts, no lists)? Also, what do you mean by 'install script'? And template editor where you can define modules? Thanks!

Comment: By install script, I mean a collection of SQL scripts, that is used to set up all the tables in the database, for the first time use.
So if you wan't to install the CMS on a new server, just use the install script, feed in the db connection, and your ready to rumble :)

User config - Options to grant access and rules to users:
User #1 is allowed to publish photos, and write posts. #2 is super admin. user #3 is only allowed to publish posts.

When user #1 logs in to the backend, he/she only sees the modules he/she has access to. Safety and usability :)